# Mobile scrolling issue with react-datepicker@2.11.0 in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-datepicker

I'm encountering an issue with react-datepicker in a React project, specifically version 2.11.0. While the date picker functions correctly on desktop, I'm facing a problem with mobile view. When viewing the date picker on a mobile device, only the first month is visible and I'm unable to scroll horizontally to view additional months.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
<div>
    <DatePicker
        selected={selectedDate}
        onChange={date => {dateChange(date)}}
        inline
        maxDate={extendedDate()}
        minDate={new Date()}
        nextMonthButtonLabel=""
        previousMonthButtonLabel=""
        monthsShown={2}
    />
</div>
```

I've tried adjusting the monthsShown prop, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue on mobile devices.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to enable horizontal scrolling for react-datepicker in mobile view? Any suggestions or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!